# Spring Boot - "this.peopleService" is null?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm a bit new to Spring Boot and I'm trying to create model/repo/service/serviceImp/controller type of architecture.

After I try to make a this get request:

```
http://localhost:8080/api/v1/people/name?name=steve
```

and I get this error (I created a couple of people in DB):

```
"java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke \"com.project.Springbootbackend.service.PeopleService.findAllByName(String)\" because \"this.peopleService\" is null\r\n\tat com.project.Springbootbackend.controller.PeopleController.findAllByName(PeopleController.java:24)
```

This is my code:
People(entity)

```
@Entity
public class People {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "surname")
    private String surname;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;
...
//constructor + get/set
```

PeopleController

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/people")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class PeopleController {

    private PeopleService peopleService;

    @GetMapping("/name")
    public ResponseEntity<List<People>> findAllByName(@RequestParam String name) {

        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(peopleService.findAllByName(name));
    }
}
```

PeopleRepo

```
public interface PeopleRepository extends JpaRepository<People, Integer> {
    List<People> findAllByName(String name);
}
```

PeopleService

```
public interface PeopleService {
    List<People> findAllByName(String name);

}
```

PeopleServiceImp

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Service
public class PeopleServiceImp implements PeopleService {

    PeopleRepository peopleRepository;

    @Override
    public List findAllByName(String name) {
        return (List) ResponseEntity.ok(peopleRepository.findAllByName(name));
    }

}
```

Thx guys in advance.

---

---

******SOLUTION:*****

---

Entity, service & repository is the same.
ServiceImp and controller changes are down belowe:

Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/people")
public class PeopleController {

    private PeopleService peopleService;

    public PeopleController(PeopleService peopleService) {
        this.peopleService = peopleService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/name")
    public ResponseEntity<List<People>> findAllByName(@RequestParam String name) {

        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(peopleService.findAllByName(name));
    }
}
```

ServiceImp

```
@Service
public class PeopleServiceImp implements PeopleService {

    private PeopleRepository peopleRepository;

    public PeopleServiceImp(PeopleRepository peopleRepository) {
        this.peopleRepository = peopleRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public List<People> findAllByName(String name) {
        List<People> people = peopleRepository.findAllByName(name);
        return people;
    }

}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you tell spring boot that you expect it to inject that service in the controller, somehow? Same with repository and service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your constructor does not inject the service, because of the `RequiredArgsConstructor` (see [Link](https://projectlombok.org/features/constructor)) needs special treatment. Therefore, use `final`:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/people")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class PeopleController {

    private final PeopleService peopleService;

    @GetMapping("/name")
    public ResponseEntity<List<People>> findAllByName(@RequestParam String name) {

        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(peopleService.findAllByName(name));
    }
}
```

Same here:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Service
public class PeopleServiceImp implements PeopleService {

    private final PeopleRepository peopleRepository;

    @Override
    public List findAllByName(String name) {
        return (List) ResponseEntity.ok(peopleRepository.findAllByName(name));
    }

}
```

Additional hint, use a typed list:

```
@Override
public List<People> findAllByName(String name) {
    return ResponseEntity.ok(peopleRepository.findAllByName(name));
}
```

Comment: If I do this, spring asks me to add constructors parametars on both classes. If I do that I get an error that "java: constructor PeopleController(com.project.Springbootbackend.service.PeopleService) is already defined in class com.project.Springbootbackend.controller.PeopleController"

Comment: I did it. I'm going to write what I did in question. Thanks for help. You helped a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
@Autowired
private PeopleService peopleService;

@Autowired
private PeopleRepository peopleRepository;
```

You also need to add the **@SpringBootApplication** annotation in the main class of the application.

Something like that:

```
@SpringBootApplication
class PeopleApplication {
public static void main(String[] args) {
...
```

Take a look at this article about automatic dependency injection in Spring:
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-autowire

Comment: I still get the same error.

Comment: Did you add the  @SpringBootApplication annotation to your application file?

Comment: I did. Now I have a new issue after I added @autowired. ""java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke \"com.project.Springbootbackend.repository.PeopleRepository.findAllByName(String)\" because \"this.peopleRepository\" is null\r\n\tat com.project.Springbootbackend.service.PeopleServiceImp.findAllByName(PeopleServiceImp.java:20)"

Comment: You also need to add another @Autowired PeopleRepository peopleRepository;

Comment: You got this error for the same reason you got your service error. You do not have an Autowired annotation on your @Autowired PeopleRepository peopleRepository. Just add it and you should be fine.

Answer (score -1):

You missed the autowiring annotation in the controller to inject the service which may make `this.peopleService` to be null.

```java
@Autowired
private PeopleService peopleService;
```

You also need to do autowire in your serviceimpl class

```java
@Autowired
private PeopleRepository peopleRepository;
```

Comment: I still get the same error.